# kubectl exec doesn't work on EKS cluster via gitlab kas

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, amazon-eks, kubectl, gitlab-api

When I'm trying to use kubectl exec in gitlab runner(kubeconfig is generating automatically by gitlab kas) request stack for ~30 sec and then return error "error: Timeout occured".

If I download this kubeconfig from runner to my localhost and try to use kubectl exec this error the same but I also have cluster installed via Kubespray and on kubespray it works properly.

**Preconditions:**

1. AWS EKS 1.23.7 fresh installed
2. Self-supported Gitlab CE 15.11.2 on AWS(gitlab and EKS cluster in a different VPC's)
3. GitLab agent installed via gitlab kas offical helmchart https://charts.gitlab.io gitlab-agent v1.13.0 with image registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/gitlab-agent/agentk:v15.11.0-rc2

**Action:**

1. Run kubectl -n {somme_namespace} {pod_name} -- ls with KUBECONFIG generated by Gitlab KAS on AWS EKS cluster

**Expected result:**

1. Command will be executed properly and without errors.

**Actual result:**

1. I'm getting error message: "error: Timeout occurred" after ~ 30 sec
   [kubectl exec with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZph9.png)

**Additional info**:

1. Other comands like *kubectl get namespaces* works fine.
2. Also I got gitlab kas url from KUBECONFIG and I've tried to perform API request directly without kubectl using wscat for open socket - it's works properly(*example request: `wscat -n -s "channel.k8s.io" -H "User-Agent:kubectl/v1.23.7 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/42c05a5" -H "Authorization:Bearer ci:87:awdawdawdawdawdawd" -H "X-Stream-Protocol-Version:v4.channel.k8s.io" -H "X-Stream-Protocol-Version:v3.channel.k8s.io" -H "X-Stream-Protocol-Version:v2.channel.k8s.io" -H "X-Stream-Protocol-Version:channel.k8s.io" -c 'https://gitlab.domain.com:4443/-/kubernetes-agent/k8s-proxy/api/v1/namespaces/gitlab-runner/pods/gitlab-runner-696db89f8d-bbt8d/exec?command=ls&stderr=true&stdout=true'`*), but in gitlab kas logs I saw that this request has type GET instead of kubectl which generate POST request.
   [API via wscat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u69WH.png)
3. [kubectl exec verbose output](https://gist.github.com/IvanPletnyov/51452e71ded2fdd6bf9fdc14e86a13ac)
4. [gitlab agent logs](https://gist.github.com/IvanPletnyov/510a83e7f47c3b855bfd67e81755e432)

**UPD 1**: On Gitlab v16.6 it works properly.